# Remove executeable bit for all userts through Powershell

Tags: powershell, file, permissions

I have an little issue that I would like to hear your openion on:

After we twice have been infected with malware in hostingcenter - we desidet to host our Servers inhouse. 
But for avoiding beeing infected again - we like to make some changes regarding permissions on local PC: 
After gathering a lot of info - I found out that malware most likely install it self in these folders: 
C:\Windows\Temp
%USERPROFILE%\Appdata\Local (Win 7/8/10/Vista)
%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings

Therefor I would like to remove the executeable bit from folder and subfolders - but is that wise - since most likely all programs are executed from %USERDATA%\AppData\Local - then no programs will run. I did try this - but couldn't start anything unless I changed it back

After googling a lot - I found out that this script is doing the most - but still having issues with ending up with all files are not executeable ???

```
# Get the ACL for an existing folder For $Users
$existingAcl = Get-Acl -Path 'C:\Windows\Temp'
# Set the permissions that you want to apply to the folder
$permissions = $env:username, 'ExecuteFile', 'ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit', 'None', 'Deny'
# Create a new FileSystemAccessRule object
$rule = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule -ArgumentList         $permissions
# Modify the existing ACL to include the new rule
$existingAcl.SetAccessRule($rule)
# Apply the modified access rule to the folder
$existingAcl | Set-Acl -Path 'C:\Windows\Temp'
```

Can someone point me the rigth way or tell me if this is no good and will destroy more than it solves

Thanks in advance
P

Comment: Sorry, what exactly is your problem? Are all files not executable after running your script, but some should OR are they still executable, but some should not?

Comment: You might try whitelisting allowed programs, and blacklisting all others, I can't know whether or not that will be scalable for you.